# Incomplete install location

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

So, there's a major beef that I have with windows and their stupid updates. I know they're helpful and all, but every time I restart my computer after installing an update there's 5 more waiting....

Anyway, I was installing battlefield 3 last night, and it stopped at 60% for me to insert disc 2 (this was while I was sleeping, it takes a while to istall). So windows decided to install it's updates at 3 A.M. and restart my computer. When I wake up this morning, I tried to put in disc 2 to complete the install, and it said `please insert disc 1`. I had to start the installation all over again.

Naturally at this point I'm not too happy, and to make matters worse I now have 7 GB less of free space on my SSD. For a 128 GB SSD, that's a lot of space. Somehow the game left the installed files on my computer, and I can't find them.

I deleted the files in the programs folder and the files in the registry, and still the 7 GB remains. I can't uninstall it in Revo Uninstaller because it doesn't show up. This is the only thing I installed yesterday, and unless the windows updates threw 7 GB of crap on my computer, I need to know what files to delete to undo this.

Comment: Have you tried listing all files on the drive by modified/creation date, or using a tool like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to see what large folders are floating around?

Comment: I have not. That sounds like a good idea, is WinDirStat a cleanup tool? I can't tell from the blog site..

Comment: It just finds files

Comment: I used WinDirStat, it worked perfectly. I found the file hidden in the temp folder, all 7 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your temp files. sometimes in win 7 programs get installed in common files or program data

Comment: I'll check there as well. Could that much data be installed here?

Comment: easiest way to find it is use windows explorer. go to detail view and hover your mouse over the folders. it should tell you how big the folder is. investigate each folder in turn until you find which one is holding large file size.

Comment: I found it using WinDirStat, the program @soandos recommended. It was in the temp files! Thanks for your help!